# EF6: saving to same entity using dbContext in async tasks

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, entity-framework-6

I load an object/entity from the database:

```
var db = new DbContext();

//...

var item = db.Items.First();
```

Then I want to perform two asynchronous tasks, that when returned, update data on the item:

```
var task1 = Function1(db, item); 
var task2 = Function2(db, item); 
await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { task1 , task2 });
```

The two functions will have some code that gets, sets & saves a (different) property on the item, like so:

```
var orderId = await CallApi();
item.OrderId = orderId;
db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

However, as they are running asynchonously, I'm getting the error: `A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed`.

I tried newing up a dbContext in the Functions, but then I get the error `An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker`.

I understand why I'm getting both of these errors, my question is: what coding pattern would best resolve this?

---

**EDIT**
Ok, so the above was a simplified example. In reality, there is a lot more work that goes on in the functions, so it would be difficult to move all that logic out of the function and into the calling method. I also want that all that work to be self-contained.

The properties on the `item` that `Function1` and `Function2` update are discrete. I'm using [this library](https://github.com/MikaelEliasson/EntityFramework.Utilities) to ensure that the save doesn't overwrite all the fields.

Comment: You can move the code db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
await db.SaveChangesAsync();  after the Task.whenall(). The job of those 2 functions is to update the properties of that object.

Comment: You can't share dbcontext between task... Create one for each task

Comment: I don't think it makes much sense to update the same database record in parallel tasks. What do you think to gain by that?

Comment: Also, by marking the entire item as modified each task will update all of its properties and the task that happens to be the last wins, erasing all changes from the other tasks.

Comment: @GertArnold I updated the question to explain a bit more.

Comment: Which makes it practically unanswerable. We don't know what's going on. Anyway, the bottom line is: don't use one context in multiple threads, ever. Just disable proxy creation in the context that executes `db.Items.First();` and/or do `db.Items.AsNoTracking().First();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the code

```
db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified; 
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

after the `Task.Whenall()`. The job of those 2 functions is to update the properties of that object.

Comment: What's the point? That's the same as *not* doing anything in parallel and calling `await db.SaveChangesAsync()` once at the end. Which, btw, is what the OP should have done in the first place

Comment: That's not obvious from the answer as it is now

Comment: That's so simple - not sure why I didn't see it! A small concern is that I want the values from the Api calls saved to the database ASAP, where this option would only save when both calls complete. I'll give this a try, though.

Answer (score 1):

Don't let two threads perform operations on the same dbContext. A dbContext keeps track of the fetched items. If two threads are fetching and changing items on the same DbContext at the same time, it might lead to undesired results.

Furthermore: if you fetched an `Item`, just change the properties you want. You don't need to set the state to Modified. A dbContext can check whether it has the original value or not.

So create functions that create their own DbContext, Fetch the requested data, change the data, save the data and finally Dispose the dbContext.

```
async Task Function1(...)
{
    using (var dbcontext = new MyDbContext(...))
    {
        // Start Fetching the item that must be changed; don't await yet
        var taskFetchItemToChange = dbContext.Items
            .Where(...)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        // Start fetching the orderId that must be changed; don't await yet
        var taskFetchOrderId = this.CallApiAsync();

        // await until both item and orderId are fetched:
        await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] {taskFetchItemToChange, taskFetchOrderId});

        var fetchedItemToChange = taskFetchItemToChange.Result;
        var fetchedOrderId = taskFetchOrderId.Result;
        fetchedItemToChange.OrderId = fetchedOrderId;
        // or do this in one big unreadable unmaintainable untestable step

        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

You will have a similar Function2, or maybe the same Function1 with different parameters.

```
var taskFunction1 = Function1();
var taskFunction2 = Function2();
await Task.WhenAll( new Task[] {taskFunction1, taskFunction2});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My concern about this approach is that the code runs in a loop many times in a second. Optimising the code performance was important. So I didn't want to new up a dbContext / fetch data every time. I should have mentioned that up front.